# using a non existing variable as a property of global object throws undefined. why?

Tags: javascript

```
//undefined . Why not a reference error instead?
console.log(window.b);
```

as there is no such global variable as b, console should throw a reference error but it says b is undefined. Which i think is implying variable b is declared globally but not assigned.

Can you explain what is happening here? (sorry if my question is silly) please explain on beginner level.

Comment: You're not reading a variable, property accessors of objects return `undefined`, if the property is not found.

Comment: Read `window.b` as `window["b"]`

Comment: At the most practical level, if reading a property that doesn't exist from an object threw an error, then writing code would be *so much more annoying*. After all, objects can have any shape at all and can even change often, so surrounding any property access with `try/catch` or whatever other error handling would just lead to tons of boilerplate code. Note that we *do* already have this situation if you call `obj.foo.bar` - the first key might not exist which *would* throw an error. And we get hundreds of questions a week because of that.

Comment: @VLAZ The latter JS pitfall fortunately has been fixed, we now have `?.` operator in the latest JS versions.

Comment: @Teemu I ran out of characters in my previous comment. But you're right. It still took *quite a while* for this to be the case. And even then we do get hundreds of questions of the type "Why does it say `obj.foo` is `undefined` - I have `obj`!". I don't really foresee the volume of these questions significantly decreasing for some time, either. People who don't understand why dereferencing a non-existing property doesn't work are unlikely to use the operator for guarding against that. So, yes it's fixed but...it still causes problems. We're in a bit of a limbo until better practices propagate.

Comment: @VLAZ True, though I think the root cause of these questions is the English error message "_Cannot read property of undefined_", for people, who have English as a third or even fourth language, the message might be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access an object in many ways. For example:

- foo.bar
- myObject['prop']

We call each of **foo**, **myObject** the **base value**. While **bar**, **prop** the **reference name**.

A reference error occurs when the reference is unresolvable. And this happens when the **base value** is **undefined**.

In your case, **window** is a global object which is defined. As a result of this, the base value is defined and this will not cause a reference error.

You can refer to this useful [link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) for more clarification on the meaning of undefined in JS.

Answer (score 1):

> Which i think is implying variable b is declared globally but not assigned.

Not really. If you try to access a property that doesn't exist from an object, you get `undefined`. Example:

```js
const obj = { a: "a" };

console.log(`Property "b" exists in obj? ${"b" in obj}`);
console.log(`Value of obj.b: ${obj.b}`);
```

The same thing happens with the global object, however, you can't use `b` directly:

```js
var a = "a";

console.log(`Property "b" exists in the global oject? ${"b" in window}`);
console.log(`Value of window.b: ${window.b}`);

try {
  console.log(`Value of b: ${b}`);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(`Not possible to get the value of b. Error:\n ${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

> The `ReferenceError` object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

but when you reference `window.b` where `window` is defined as an `object` then accessing `b` is requesting a non existing object and according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) default value for non existing object properties is `undefined`